# How to align "radio" and "checkbox" icons in the context menu in Android OS?

Tags: android, icons, alignment, contextmenu

In the context menu, the "radio" and "checkbox" icons are shown with different margins from the edge. How to make margins the same for all icons in menu?

[image]

This is how the menu is described in the XML resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:id="@+id/groupSortMode"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_sort_by_plan"
            android:title="@string/action_context_menu_sort_by_plan"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_sort_by_name"
            android:title="@string/action_context_menu_sort_by_name"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            />
    </group>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_group_by_clients"
        android:title="@string/action_context_menu_group_by_clients"
        android:checkable="true"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: check your menu xml my side not show margins

Comment: @suresh-madaparthi
I've drawn a dotted red line on the screenshot to show the margins.